# Can't access variable passed into constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on a controller that is using express. I believe the issue is the way the project is setup is that the routes are initialized in the constructor. But I am not 100%, but when I `console.log(this._messageService)`, I get undefined (this is when I call the route directly using postman).

> [1] (node:30820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_messageService' of undefined

**index.ts**

```js
export const app = new App(
  [
    new MessageController(new MessageService()),
  ],
  8080
);

app.listen();
```

**message.controller.ts**

```js
class MessageController implements IController {
 public path = "/message";
 public router = express.Router();
 public intializeRoutes() {
   this.router.get("/", this.get);
 }

 constructor(private readonly _messageService: MessageService) {
   this.intializeRoutes();
 }

 async get(req: Request, res: Response) {
   console.log(this._messageService); <=== 
   const data = await this._messageService.getAll();
   res.send(data);
 }
}

export default MessageController;
```

Comment: I think you might be passing the method as value without binding it with `this`. Try adding `this.get = this.get.bind(this)` in the constructor.

Comment: Aha! "this" makes complete sense. Thank you